# Getting the length of an array of objects in Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of objects:

```
const boxOptions = [
  { 0: "$250", 1: "$500", 2: "$750", 3: "$1000", 4: "$1250", 5: "$1500" },
  { 0: "$500", 1: "$750", 2: "$1000", 3: "$1250", 4: "$1500", 5: "$2000" },
  { 0: "$750", 1: "$1000", 2: "$1250", 3: "$1500", 4: "$2000", 5: "$2500" },
]
```

Which is set to the state and then rendered in my RangeSlider component:

```
 state = {
    boxOptions: boxOptions,
    tier: 0
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <RangeSlider label='What sort of box are you after?' onChange={this.handleBoxChange} min={0} max={5} defaultValue={this.state.boxIndex} marks={this.state.boxOptions[this.state.tier]} step={null} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

When I try to get the length of it on my onChange handler, I get undefined:

```
  handleBoxChange = index => {
    console.log(this.state.boxOptions[this.state.tier].length, 'boxOptions')
  }
```

Why is this?

[Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/x9kz8olrmz)

Comment: `this.state.boxOptions[this.state.tier]` is an object, not an array. Did you mean `this.state.boxOptions.length`?

Comment: your sandbox link doest work , Not sure if only for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.state.boxOptions[this.state.tier].length
```

`this.state.boxOptions[this.state.tier]` will work and return `{ 0: "$250", 1: "$500", 2: "$750", 3: "$1000", 4: "$1250", 5: "$1500" }` however, Object doesn't have the property `.length` and this is why it returns undefined.

If you wanted the total number of properties on this object, you can use:

```
Object.keys(this.state.boxOptions[this.state.tier]).length
```

`Object.keys(object)` will return you an array of all the keys within an Object

Comment: Thank you! I'm AFK atm but will confirm it works shortly and then accept as accepted answer when it allows me. Edit: just what I needed. Thanks again